# Is it necessary to remove all warnings of android studio before launching the app to google play store?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

Hope everyone is doing fine . I am planning to launch my first android app to google play store .I am little bit confused whether is it mandatory to remove all the warnings in java files and .xml files before launching it to play store?

Comment: Its up to you, whether you want to remove it or not. Its not necessary to remove the warnings.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nainal

Answer (score 0):

usually, errors are not important for releasing an app in google play. But, for better user experience, you should debug your app and fix errors. The most important thing is to make your app compatible with the rules. For example, your app should not contain other apps' name.